# Run server-side js from php through exec()

Tags: php, node.js, exec, server-side

I have a site running on Apache/PHP, and as a matter of performance, I wrote a javascript to do a specific task.

I have installed node.js on server, in order to run this javascript. When I call the script from the command line, it works fine. See the command below:

```
> node myscript.js
```

But I need it to run from a php page, and I am trying to do this by calling the exec() PHP function, like this:

```
<?php exec('node myscript.js >/dev/null/ 2>&1 &'); ?>
```

...but it's not working.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: probably a permission issue

Comment: Try executing it with values for output and return_var to see output and status of the cmd respectively. Helps with debugging :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I set the 777 permission to the js, but still not working...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to make it work! I just wrote the full directory where node.js is installed in the exec() call. Simple as that:

```
<?php exec('/home/bin/node myscript.js >/dev/null/ 2>&1 &'); ?>
```